# how to share a link on facebook without using third party library?

Tags: ios

i have doubt to implement share link on facebook and twitter.
actually  i implemented social share link using sharekit and addThis third party library it working fine but i want share link without using third party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 6, You can use `UIActivityViewController` to share your link to Social services.

Reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityViewController

It is as easy as these few lines:

```
NSString *textToShare = @”I just shared this from my App”;
UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];
NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mylink.com"];
NSArray *activityItems = @[textToShare, imageToShare, urlToShare];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

Comment: iOS 5.1 does not have built in Facebook integration. You'll have to use their-part libraries for that. However it does have a native twitter sharing API.

Comment: welcome. You can mark as answer by clicking on the tick mark below the voting control.